# DataTables enclose source array into JSON 'data' property

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I am trying to create a datatable with data I've gotten through a jQuery ajax GET request. The GET request returns all of the objects in the format

```
[{
    "id": "88776",
    "employee_name": "JohnhmO",
    "employee_salary": "13973",
    "employee_age": "19",
    "profile_image": ""
},
{
    "id": "88778",
    "employee_name": "jbmvy",
    "employee_salary": "123",
    "employee_age": "23",
    "profile_image": ""
}]
```

I need to enclose source array into JSON 'data' property so that datatables can read it.

I've tried parsing into JSON. I've tried unshift.

```
var dataSet = '';
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees',
    type: 'GET',
    datatype: 'json'
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    dataSet = data;
})
function unshiftFunc(dataSet) {
    dataSet.unshift('data:');
}
console.log(dataSet)
```

What I'm looking for is this:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": "88776",
        "employee_name": "JohnhmO",
        "employee_salary": "13973",
        "employee_age": "19",
        "profile_image": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "88778",
        "employee_name": "jbmvy",
        "employee_salary": "123",
        "employee_age": "23",
        "profile_image": ""
    }]
}
```

Comment: `What I'm looking for is this:` This isn't valid JSON.

Comment: JSON isn't relevant anyway; you're going to *parse* the JSON string and end up with a JavaScript array.  You can't add a label to the beginning of the array; it's nonsense syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may keep your JSON as is and still populate DataTables successfully if you employ [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option instead of *external* `$.ajax()` call which may get you into different sorts of issues:

```
$('table').DataTable({
   ...
   ajax: {
      url: 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees',
      type: 'GET',
      dataSrc: ''
   }
});
```

Option `dataSrc: ''` [indicates](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) that your source data is array of objects not enclosed into any particular property.

Comment: Ahh ok, Joseph's comment below made sense but I see how that could mess up the table. This worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant putting the returned array in an object, keyed with the property name `data`. In that case, simply create an object, and assign your data into the `data` property.

```
.done(function(data){
   dataSet = { data: data };
})
```

By the way, `console.log(dataSet)` will return `undefined` since `$.ajax` is asynchronous. You'll have to do that inside `done`'s callback to know what `dataSet` looks like after the AJAX resolves.

Comment: While this one is perfectly valid *jQuery* answer, it is inappropriate from DataTables API standpoint. If OP moves on with his current approach, he's going to have to purge/destroy DataTable in order to refresh that (which is a performance waste). Furthermore, if he tries to implement certain features, he may run into all sorts of AJAX-issues and left with some crucial DataTables API methods invalidated. **Instead**,  [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option should be suggested with proper `dataSrc` value (see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56945431/11299053)).

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `Array.concat()` to add things together in the way you want.

`data = ["data"].concat(data);`